# How to duplicate an arc_ecto upload

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, arc-ecto

One of the models of my Phoenix app has a logo, which uses `arc_ecto` and uploads to S3.

I'm duplicating one of the records and I want it to have the same image as a logo.

In my changeset I have:

```
|> cast_attachments(params, [:logo])
```

The value of the logo for the original item is:

```
iex(21)> MyRepo.get(MyModel, 1).logo
%{file_name: "mylogo.png",
updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2017-09-12 12:31:58>}
```

But if I try to set that directly, I get an error (Arc.File.new doesn't accept that structure, that makes sense).

I also tried extracting the S3 url of the original logo. This didn't return an error, but also didn't add the logo:

```
iex(22)> MyRepo.get(MyModel, 2).logo
nil
```

What's the right way to manage this scenario? Any hints?

Comment: Can you post the `schema` declaration of `MyModel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue, there were 2 things missing:

1 - Needed to add `allow_paths: true` to `cast_attachments`

```
|> cast_attachments(params, [:logo], allow_paths: true)
```

2 - I had this on the uploader:

```
def storage_dir(_version, {_file, my_model}) do
  "/my_models/#{my_model.id}/logo/"
end
```

So I was using the id to set the storage route. As I was duplicating the element, I still didn't have an ID and therefore the route was incorrect. I split the insert of the duplicated element and the update of the logo into 2 steps.